# Retrieving how many transactions were made on a date in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table named `Sales` and a column within it named `Date`. I'm simply trying to find how many sales were made on a specific date. My intuition was to use something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Date) FROM Sales WHERE Date='2015-04-04'
```

this should count all sales that were made on that date, but that returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Are you using Date=2015-04-04 or Date='2015-04-04'? And are you sure that there are sales in your table with this date?

Comment: Doh, I left off the ''s. Stupid mistake. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

While it is difficult to be precise without table definitions or an indication of what RDBMS you are using, it is likely that `Date` is a time/date stamp, and that the result you want would be obtained either by looking for a range from the beginning of the day to the end of the day in your `WHERE` clause, or by truncating `Date` down to a date without the time before comparing it to a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below once.

```
select count(*) from <t.n> where date like '2015-04-04%';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to find the count of rows based on a field (`Date`) You need to `Group By` over it like this:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(*)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Date
```

Now you have all count of rows for each `Date`.
Type and Value of Date is important in the result of the above query.

For example in SQL Server your best try is to convert a `DateTime` field to `varchar` and then check it as the result of [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Sales
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 111) = '2015/04/04'
```